# How to send file from client to server to another client?

Tags: java

what I want ask is could I do something with file? which Stream is file send by ?Should file change to another data?

Comment: This question is too light on detail.

Comment: You've to be specific that 1) what do u really want to do with that file (reading/manipulating to another structure) 2) Your question is ambiguous that: In what context you mean 'server'? Is it intranet or internet. Be specific always, so that you can get answers...

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file using an `InputStream` and write its data to the `OutputStream` of a `Socket`.

This may look something like this:

```
OutputStream out = null;
FileInputStream in = null;

try {
    // Input from file
    String pathname = "path/to/file.dat";
    File file = new File(pathname);
    in = new FileInputStream(file);

    // Output to socket
    String host = "10.0.1.8";
    int port = 6077;
    Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
    socket.connect(endpoint); // TODO: define endpoint
    out = socket.getOutputStream();

    // Transfer
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        out.write(in.read());
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception

} finally {
    if (out != null)
        out.close();
    if (in != null)
        in.close();
}
```

PS: I'm not sure if this actually works. It's meant to get you started...